# $\tan x=4-3\cos x $. Solve for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Given that $$\tan x=4-3\cos x \space$$

Solve it in the range of $0^\circ \leq x \leq 180^\circ$

I tried many methods but it ended nowhere. Hope someone can provide a clear solution for this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put this into Wolfram Alpha, there seems to be an algebraic answer but it's quite complicated. Do you need an algebraic solution or a numerical one?
Wolfram Alpha's solution begins by setting $y= \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$.

Comment: Using double angle formula $$\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}=4-\dfrac{3(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}=\dfrac{1+7t^2}{1+t^2}$$

$$\iff2t+2t^3=1+6t^2-7t^4$$

Comment: *"I tried many methods but it ended nowhere"* What mathematical methods did you use? Could you please show us how you applied them?

Comment: I've tried @labbhattacharjee method. But I realise it's hard to solve a quartic equation without an integer root.

Comment: @Mathxx Is this problem from a book? Which one?

Comment: You can get this to the form $4\cos x - \sin x = 3\cos^2x$ or $\frac4{\sqrt{17}}\cos x - \frac1{\sqrt{17}}\sin x = \frac3{\sqrt{17}}\cos^2x$.
If $\alpha$ is an angle with $\cos\alpha=\frac4{\sqrt{17}}$ and $\sin\alpha=\frac1{\sqrt{17}}$, then you have $\cos (x+\alpha)=\frac3{\sqrt{17}}\cos^2x$. Now you could express $\cos^2x$ using $\cos 2x$ and try the similar approach once again. Although the solution will probably not have a very nice form.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, but it  is very ugly.
$$\tan(x)=4-3\cos(x)$$
$$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=4-3\cos(x)$$
$$\sin(x)=4\cos(x)-3\cos^2(x)$$
$$\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}=4\cos(x)-3\cos^2(x)$$
Let $u=\cos(x)$:
$$\sqrt{1-u^2}=4u-3u^2$$
$$1-u^2=16u^2-24u^3+9u^4$$
$$9u^4-24u^3+17u^2-1=0$$
Plugging this into wolfram alpha, we get $u = 0.309609$ and so $x = \cos^{-1}(u) = 1.256$

Hope this helped.

Comment: You forgot to check your answers for extraneous roots. If you do that you will find that your second answer is extraneous: the two sides of the original equation are negatives of each other. There are other roots of the original equation but they are outside the domain $0\le x\le 180°$.

Comment: Ah, that was likely caused by the squaring. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\tan x=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x} $, so $\sin x=\cos x(4-3 \cos x)$.

We set $\sin x=u, \cos x=v$, so we have

$u=v(4-3v)$, and $u^2+v^2=1$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I don't see how the identity $u^2 + v^2 = 1$ helps here. Can you clarify on how it is used in the expression?

Comment: @TobyMak: Square both sides of $u=v(4-3v)$ then remove the $u^2$ on the left using $u^2=1-v^2$. You then have a fourth-degree equation in $u$. Solve that. Note that this is similar to lab's comment--you just end up with a different 4th-degree equation, but this way was easier to get the equation. Both equations are difficult to solve, of course, but there's no way around that.

Comment: @Rory Daulton Thanks

Comment: @TobyMak: Oops, I meant you get a fourth-degree equation in $v$--I mistakenly typed $u$.